# ¿Por qué se conjuga un arreglo complejo en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices

Trabajando en python, con el siguiente arreglo matricial 2x2 de entrada compleja, se cambia de signo no sé si al imprimir, o cuando lee y almacena en la variable, es decir me aparece el conjugado de lo que escribo, tanto usando numpy como sympy:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
B=np.array([[1/4-np.sqrt(7)/4j,1/4+np.sqrt(7)/4j],[1,1]])
#B=sp.Matrix([[1/4-sp.sqrt(7)/4j,1/4+sp.sqrt(7)/4j],[1,1]])
print(B)
```

e imprime esto:

```
[[0.25+0.66143783j 0.25-0.66143783j]
 [1.  +0.j         1.  +0.j        ]]
```

¿Por qué se debe esto?, cómo lo arreglo sin cambiar de signo, puesto que puede llegar a crear confusiones.
Gracias

Comment: Hola Germán. Seguramente no sea nuevo para ti pero hay que recordar que la  representación de números complejos toma la forma a+ib y tanto numpy como sympy los representan siguiendo dicha forma y por eso calculan el conjugado. No veo la manera de poder cambiar dicho comportamiento.

Comment: @David no hay relación entre la forma en que se representan y el hecho de que la parte imaginaria cambie de signo (que es lo que se pregunta).

Answer (score 0):

Se debe a que `1/1j` produce como resultado `-1j`, pues
la inversa de `j` es `-j` (ya que `j*-j` es 1).

En tu expresión `1/4-np.sqrt(7)/4j` el `4j` está en el denominador, de ahí el supuesto "cambio de signo". Si quieres que sólo el 4 esté en el denominador y no la `j`, tendrás que usar paréntesis, así por ejemplo:

```
1/4-(np.sqrt(7)/4)*1j
```

o cambiar de sitio la `j`:

```
1/4-np.sqrt(7)*1j/4
```